# How to use CSSModules in PHP (non SPA)

Tags: php, webpack, postcss, css-modules

So I want to use the benefits of CSSModules in a regular PHP project (a wordpress theme to be more specific). I am using webpack with autoprefixer, browsersync, postcss and more to compile and hot reload parts of the project while developing. I understand that there is also a plugin to postcss called [postcss-modules](https://github.com/css-modules/postcss-modules) which I would like to use.

The plugin is adding hashes to all my css classes and outputting a json with the mappings, as expected. Now I would like to bind one css module (which is a scss-file uncompiled) to each php file (as you would do when using css modules in React). How should I do this? I would still like the css to resist in one large file after compiling.

This is a part of my webpack config:

```
  {
    test: /\.(scss|css)$/,
    use: extractSass.extract({
      use: [{
        loader: "css-loader"
      },
      {
        loader: 'postcss-loader',
        options: {
          plugins: function () {
            return [
              require('precss'),
              require('autoprefixer'),
              require('cssnano'),
              require('postcss-modules')
            ];
          }
        }
      },
      {
        loader: "sass-loader"
      }],
      fallback: "style-loader"
    })
  },
```

And I am using a main.js and a style.scss as entry point in webpack. The style.scss is then importing all the partial scss-files (which should be one css module each).

Answer (score 4):

I did a [really good writeup](https://matlipe.com/using-postcss-modules-in-php/) on how to do all this. The only difference is I am using grunt-postcss instead of Webpack to handle the postcss plugins and functionality. Should be straightforward to port the concepts over to Webpack.

The key is to configure postcss-modules to handle the separate pcss files as modules. That way you can parse the JSON separately per module. Using globalModulePaths you are able to keep your main pcss intact and append your modules to it.

Comment: A link to a potential solution is always welcome, but what you've put here so far is really the bare minimum which might be considered an answer. As such, I wouldn't be surprised to see some people down-vote this answer. While I understand your already existing write-up is merely similar instead of exactly what the OP is asking for, it's always better to have something a bit more fleshed-out than this currently is. As this is, it really feels more like a comment than an answer, but it's certainly on it's way to being an answer.

Comment: People here tend to be quite sensitive about users linking to (promoting) their own sites. If you're going to link to your own site, you should read: [What signifies "Good" self promotion?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/182212) and [How to not be a spammer](//stackoverflow.com/help/promotion). It's possible to do a good job of linking to your own site. Just be aware that it's something that people may jump on you for, if you, even by mistake, end up not following what's in the above links. Good luck.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback Makyen. I would have loved to comment instead of answer, unfortunately I don't have enough rep to do so. I was honestly just trying to be helpful. If someone else has a better answer, please down vote mine. Until then I really hope this can help someone find there way to a working solution. I couldn't find an answer, so I made one.